# Get non-default EM in Symfony2 test

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a Symfony2 unit test in which I get the entity manager like this:

```
$this->_em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

This works fine for the *default* entity manager, but I want to get another entity manager called `core`, which exists in addition to `default`. How can I do this?

I tried this just for kicks and it didn't work:

```
$this->_em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_managers.core');
```

Comment: get('doctrine.orm.core_entity_manager') should also work. Useful if you want to pass the core em to a service.  php console container:debug is also a useful command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager('core')
```

You should read [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

Comment: It didn't like it. `Fatal error: Call to undefined method appTestDebugProjectContainer::getDoctrine() in /home/jason/pressbox/src/VNN/PressboxBundle/Tests/Entity/UserTest.php on line 16`